# Image mask filter

Tags: c#, image, optimization, mask, unsafe

I have 3 System.Drawing.Bitmap objects. A RGB foreground, RGB background, and a single byte per pixel mask image where 0 means take the background pixel and 1 means take the foreground pixel. All three are the same dimensions.

I chose to use the Bitmap objects because I need to eventually run this code in MonoTouch and MonoDroid. I can rethink that if needed.

The code I have is optimized but still seems slow. This is also the slowest part of the whole operation so I would like to optimize it more. I also can't help but think there is some secret method that will do all this for me.

If it helps. Prior to this point all 3 are byte[]'s which I turn into images and re-size to uniform dimensions. If I could do things better one step back then let me know.

The code below is what I am currently using and essentially updates the background image with the appropriate foreground pixels.

```
        BitmapData backgroundData = background.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, background.Width, background.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, background.PixelFormat);
        int backgroundPixelSize = GetPixelSize(backgroundData);

        BitmapData foregroundData = foreground.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, foreground.Width, foreground.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, foreground.PixelFormat);
        int foregroundPixelSize = GetPixelSize(foregroundData);

        BitmapData maskData = mask.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, mask.Width, mask.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, mask.PixelFormat);
        //int maskPixelSize = GetPixelSize(maskData);

        for (int y = 0; y < background.Height; y++)
        {
            byte* backgroundRow = (byte*)backgroundData.Scan0 + (y * backgroundData.Stride);
            byte* foregroundRow = (byte*)foregroundData.Scan0 + (y * foregroundData.Stride);
            byte* maskRow = (byte*)maskData.Scan0 + (y * maskData.Stride);

            for (int x = 0; x < background.Width; x++)
            {
                // Check if the mask byte is set
                if (maskRow[x] > 0)
                {
                    // Copy the bytes over
                    for (int p = 0; p < backgroundPixelSize; p++)
                    {
                        backgroundRow[x * backgroundPixelSize + p] = foregroundRow[x * foregroundPixelSize + p];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Update:** 
The two images are 3 bytes per pixel and the mask image is 1 byte per pixel.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If you know the images will be 24-bit RGB, removing the inner `backgroundPixelSize` loop should give you a pretty decent speedup right away.

Comment: @CoryNelson I will test and see. The loop does have a small overhead which is not needed. I was thinking generally when I don't necessarily need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code. I think it's more fastly and clear (in case of all three images have same sizes).

```
BitmapData backgroundData = background.LockBits(
    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, background.Width, background.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

BitmapData foregroundData = foreground.LockBits(
    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, foreground.Width, foreground.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

BitmapData maskData = mask.LockBits(
    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, mask.Width, mask.Height), 
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

uint* backgroundPtr = (uint*)backgroundData.Scan0;
uint* foregroundPtr = (uint*)foregroundData.Scan0;
uint* maskPtr = (uint*)maskData.Scan0;

int dataLength = backgroundData.Height * backgroundData.Width;

for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
    if (maskPtr[i] > 0)
        backgroundPtr[i] = foregroundPtr[i];
```

**UPDATE**

Also it is possible to use mask PixelFormat:

```
BitmapData maskData = mask.LockBits(
    new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, mask.Width, mask.Height), 
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, mask.PixelFormat);
byte* maskPtr = (byte*)maskData.Scan0;

int dataLength = backgroundData.Height * backgroundData.Width;
for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)
    if (maskPtr[i] > 0)
        backgroundPtr[i] = foregroundPtr[i];
```

Comment: All 3 are the same size but the mask image is a single byte per pixel. The other two are strictly RGB and have 24 bytes per pixel.

Comment: @Telavian, I guess my code can be applied to your case bacause of `LockBits` method prepare appropriate arrays depend on `PixelFormat` parameter (in my code `Format32bppArgb`).

Comment: I don't think you can go through linearly because sometimes each row is padded to align for word boundaries. Thus the Stride value is needed. http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm

Comment: @Telavian, the Stride value is not needed, because of `LockBits` method convert image to required format.